# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 in apache tomcat DataSourceFactory

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, classloader

I have run out of ideas on this despite reading all the related posts and understanding the problem as I thought. When I run my app in tomcat, it decrypts a DB password as part of the initialization using custom code I wrote. This decryption utility passes back a DataSourceFactory.

It throws this error:

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceFactory : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

I have built the decryption utility as a jar using JDK 1.6.0.31.1 and the hex value of bytes 6 and 7 in all compiled class files inside this jar is Ox31 = 49 decimal, which denotes J2SE5 compatible.

In addition the only tomcat-jdbc in my tomcat lib folder is tomcat-jdbc-7.0.37.jar. Opening this and again examining the major.minor byte positions in the DataSourceFactory class shows the same Ox31.

I have noticed that a tomcat-jdbc-8.0.8.jar was appearing in the dependency tree on the utility (I am building using maven). The DataSourceFactory in 8.0.8 does have Ox51 in the major.minor verison bytes, denoting it was built with Java7. I removed this and rebuilt but it made no difference which is not surprising as this surely is a runtime problem only.

I am running tomcat with the same version of java 1.6.0.31.

Still somehow Tomcat it seems to be trying to load a newer verision of DataSourceFactory at runtime despite it not being in the lib folder - I have printed out every class in that folder and there is no hidden extra class within some other jar or anything like that.

Any idea what I might try to find where it's getting loaded from?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Groan, there was a tomcat-jdbc-8.0.8 in the guts in Intellij somewhere which was getting picked up by the tomcat running within the IDE.